# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (9)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am actually scraping the data from the shopping website Flipkart and save it to the products.csv file that contains the name of the products, their prices and the rating.

```
for a in soup.find_all("a", href = True, attrs = {"class" : "_31qSD5"}):
   name = a.find("div" , attrs = {"class":"_3wU53n"})
   price = a.find("div" , attrs = {"class":"_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"})
   rating = a.find("div" , attrs = {"class":"hGSR34"})
   products.append(name.text)
   prices.append(price.text)
   rating.append(rating.text)


df = pd.DataFrame({"Product_Name":products, "Prices":prices, "Ratings":rating})
```

The above code is working good but the line below gives this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (9)
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: We are missing your input data. Please update your question and provide a minimal working example.